# MySQL trigger to calculate status field before update

Tags: mysql, triggers

We have a status field on our "wo" table that is currently calculated on the fly, and is becoming a performance problem because as you can see below it touches thousands of records per wo record - making reporting etc problematic.

I'm a bit of a newbie to triggers but what i'm trying to do is create a mysql trigger to calculate the status on update and store it on the wo record.  [Create trigger code] http://pastie.org/5352756  (couldn't get it formatted properly here).

I can confirm that the query to calculate the status works on it's own (if i hardcode the woID at the end).

When i try to create this trigger, i'm getting response "Query was empty".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - issue was with the delimiters.